# Is it possible to force knockout to parse new bindings added via html binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am adding some simple html when the user clicks a table row. The table row gets "expanded" and the the html is added via the knockout html binding.

The html being injected to the view works fine, but I have added `data-bind` to some of the html and would like for knockout to parse/process it. Is this possible?

Comment: I think what you should be doing is using knockout templates/foreaches to generate the HTML, and create more JavaScript objects to force Knockout to make the HTML.

Comment: I have a specific use case in mind. I'm building a plugin for internal use and would really like the ability to do what I have asked about.

Comment: Is there a reason the other way wouldn't work?

Comment: In any case, you can just call `ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#new-html-stuff')[0]);`

Comment: I will try both ways thanks.

Comment: @ColinDeClue if you answer the question with your above answer I would accept it because for now that is the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you add the HTML, call apply bindings again but restrict what HTML you're looking at to just the newly-added HTML, like so:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#new-html")[0]);
```